# Unable to run more than one plugins in gradle

Tags: gradle, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd, build.gradle

I have configured pmd, checkstyle and findbugs plugins in gradle.build file as i want to maintain the quality the codeline.

Part of my build.gradle property is:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
description = "Generates gradlew (for internal use only)"
gradleVersion = '1.5'
jarFile = 'wrapper/wrapper.jar'
}

subprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'findbugs' //TODO: disable findbugs & checkstyle by default.
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

pmd.ignoreFailures = true
findbugs.ignoreFailures = true

findbugsMain.enabled = true
findbugsTest.enabled = true

checkstyleTest.enabled = true
checkstyleMain.enabled = true

checkstyle {
   configFile = new File(rootDir, "config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
   ignoreFailures = true
}
```

My intention is to get all the warnings/errors for pmd, findbugs and checkstyle.

I am trying **gradlew check** but i am not able to see any certain behavior. At times findbugs alone runs.

Can anybody suggest where i am missing?

Thanks in advance,
Vijay Bhore

Answer (score 0):

get you list the output of your

```
./gradlew check
```

invocation. Usually this should work, though enabling your tasks manually (e.g. 'findbugsMain.enabled = true') shouldnt be necessary.

cheers,

René

Comment: Hey Rene, i am observing a strange behavior. When i run .\gradlew check, it doesn't execute any of the plugin tasks. It ran once, created pmd, findbugs, checkstyle folders under subproject's build/reports folder. When i run the command now, the folder is there but not refreshed. is this behavior expected?

Comment: One more observation, a colleague of mine checked in few files. I got the updated code and ran gradlew check. I found that findbugs, pmd and checkstyle warnings are generated only for the changed code. I guess, unless the code is changed, the repeated execution of gradlew check doesn't produce new warnings.

Comment: Yes, that's the case - gradle does not re-run tasks if things have not changed.